# Strange inheritance problem "cannot be invoked without 'new'"

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs

Thought I had this figured out yesterday, but I apparently did not and after another full day of trying to figure this out I'm asking for help again.

I have a module that is "installed" via `npm link` which is written in ES6.  There is a class that I am exporting called Perishable. I have stripped down the class to the bare minimum are the issue still exists.

```
export default class Perishable {
    constructor() {

    }
}
```

I am trying to extend the class, and I am doing so like this:

```
// Perishable is imported already and IS NOT NULL. 
export default class Apple extends Perishable {
    constructor() {
        super()
    }
}
```

When calling `new Apple()` I get the following error:  `Class constructor Perishable cannot be invoked without 'new'`

However, I can directly create a new Perishable class via `new Perishable()` without any problems.

---

To add onto this, copy+pasting the class into the same directory and importing it using a relative path allows me to properly call `new Apple()`.  I believe this has to do with the way that webpack/babel is transpiling the symlinked class.  This is what I get when inspecting the transpiled code: of the symlinked class

```
var Apple = function (_Perishable) {
    _inherits(Apple,  _Perishable);

    function Apple() {
        _classCallCheck(this, Apple);

        return _possibleConstructorReturn(this, (Apple.__proto__ || Object.getPrototypeOf(Apple)).call(this));
    }

    return Apple;
}(_idleEngine.Perishable);
```

This is what I get when I inspect the code of the local class (that works properly).

```
var Apple = function (_Perishable) {
    _inherits(Apple, _Perishable);

    function Apple() {
        _classCallCheck(this, Apple);

        return _possibleConstructorReturn(this, (Apple.__proto__ || Object.getPrototypeOf(Apple)).call(this));
    }

    return Apple;
}(_Perishable3.default);
```

The only difference between the two generated codes is what's in the curlies at the end, one is `(_idleEngine.Perishable)` and one is `(_Perishable3.default)`.

`console.log(Perishable)` returns the same thing for both types of imports, and `new Perishable()` works fine for both imports.

---

I should add that the symlinked class is imported via a `npm link` and the `local` class I just copy+pasted out of the library to be in the same folder as the Apple class.

---

EDIT: This seems to only be a problem with syslinked modules as publishing the module "fixed" the issue.

Comment: I assume you are still stuck on Babel 6.x?

Comment: @connexo Yeah, that's correct. The issue seems to only exist when syslinked. If I publish the module then it works as expected.

Comment: I'd suggest you migrate to Babel 7 asap. If not possible, use the appropriate plugin named `babel-plugin-transform-classes-proposal` or something the like of that.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-classes

Comment: *"I have a module that is "installed" via npm link which is written in ES6."* That's likely the problem. I assume that whatever is invoking babel on your code is not configured to go into the linked module (or it may even be that tools are not able to do that). So the super class is a native ES6 class, which means that it must be called with `new`, which the tranpiled code doesn't (and cannot) do.

Comment: I'll upgrade to babel7 and if that doesn't work I'll try the classes plugin. Thanks